# flash list component with buttons

Tags: flash

Is there a way to **add buttons in a flash List component** ? (**Flash cs5**, not Flex !)

If not, any alternative to do it ?

Regards.

Comment: Add pre-existing buttons to the List component? or use the Label objects in the List component as buttons?

Answer (score 0):

If you want to use the Label objects in the List component like buttons, you can add an event listener to the List componenent that listens for `ListEvent.ITEM_CLICK` as you can see in the following:

```
package
{
    import fl.controls.List;
    import fl.data.DataProvider;
    import fl.events.ListEvent;
    import flash.display.Sprite

    public class ListExample extends Sprite
    {   
        public function ListExample() 
        {
           init();

        }// end function

        private function init():void
        {
            var buttons:Array = new Array("Mouse", "Cat", "Dog");

            var list:List = new List();
            list.dataProvider = new DataProvider(buttons);
            addChild(list);

            list.addEventListener(ListEvent.ITEM_CLICK, onListItemClick);
        }

        private function onListItemClick(e:ListEvent):void
        {
            switch(e.item.label)
            {
                case "Mouse" : trace("Mice eat cheese"); break;
                case "Cat" : trace("Cats eat the mice"); break;
                case "Dog" : trace("Dogs eat cats"); break;

            }// end switch

        }// end function

    }// end class

}// end package
```

You can add a conditional in the listener function onListItemClick() to differentiate between the labels that are clicked and then invoke the correspoding code. In the preceding example, I use a switch statement.